# How to display content after certain amount of time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how can I display a div container after a certain amount of time, say 10 seconds. Also, I'm using a `CLASS` and no `ID`.

I already tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".contentPost").delay(5000).fadeIn(500);
});
```

And CSS:

```
.contentPost {
    display: none;
}
```

However that doesn't really work for me anymore... Any other ideas?

Comment: Do you have the element visible if you remove the `display: none`?

Comment: Yes! I inserted the JS Code to the Custom JS code in my Theme options and think it is blocked by a plugin, because it works with disabled Plugin...

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeout`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   setTimeout(function(){ $(".contentPost").fadeIn(500); }, 10000);        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use plain javascript also.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  document.querySelector('.contentPost').className = "";
}, 5000)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ananthaprakashb/8jrdwrrL/